# Index of specific element in a multi-dimensional list using Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, declarative

I'm trying to find out if there is any way to find specific element index in a multi dimensional list, for example `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`?

How to find index of '5' -  [2][2] or get value  [3][3] ? Is this possible without when size of the list is unknown? Or is there any built-in predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nth1/3 to achieve it:

```
index(Matrix, Row, Col, Value):-
  nth1(Row, Matrix, MatrixRow),
  nth1(Col, MatrixRow, Value).
```

Test cases:

```
?- index([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 2, 2, X).
X = 5.

?- index([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], Row, Col, 5).
Row = Col, Col = 2 ;
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Anyway i will try to redefine it how hard coudl it be?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to rewrite nth1/3 ? It shouldn't be complicated, and you might want to see the implementation `listing(nth1/3)` et al.